# PDO заменяются знаки больше и меньше

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Добрый день.
Пользуюсь PDO.
Есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_ads  AND ad_price>:minprice AND ad_price>:maxprice ORDER BY ad_parse_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Далее выполняю запрос следующим образом:

```
if($minprice!=""&&$maxprice!=""){
$where = $where." AND ad_price>:minprice AND ad_price<:maxprice"; 
$fields[":minprice"] = $minprice;
$fields[":maxprice"] = $maxprice;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
foreach($fields as $key => $value)
{
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

При этом возникает ошибка вида:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND ad_price&gt;'1000000' AND ad_price&gt;'1500000'
```

Вижу, что знак > и < заменяется на соответствующие gt и lt. Как можно это побороть?

Comment: Скажу может глупость, но почему знаки у вас вплотную к именам? может стоит разнести пробелами? Парсер же не на столько умный, чтоб считать, что это уже не имя колонки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пробовал, не помогает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ведь тут не весь код  куда делся $where в запросе участвует $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
Вот где-то на этапе собирания условий из select where итд в query у вас наверно и стоит что-то вроде htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

Цитируемый кусок запроса в сообщении об ошибке mysql всегда начинается **сразу** за проблемным местом.

Так что ошибка не в замене символов > и <, а в отсутствующем операторе WHERE. Замена же скорее всего производится при выводе сообщения об ошибке и не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score -1):

Не думаю что решу вашу проблему, но, например, у меня на **PHP 5.6** с **PDO** порядок, вот часть кода :

```
$db_0_OBJ   =   $DB_MYSQL_INIT_FUNC_NAME();
$sqlCond_STR=   $COL_TBL_NUM.' = :tblNum_INT AND '.$COL_MAT_STATE.' = '.$MAT_STATE_ACT.' AND '.$COL_LIN_1_UCO.' < :tblUcoDataLine1UcoMax_INT '.
                'ORDER BY '.$COL_LINED.' ASC, '.$COL_LINSOR.' ASC';
$query_OBJ  =   $db_0_OBJ->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.PRK::$DBT_MATS_LIST.' WHERE '.$sqlCond_STR.' LIMIT 1');
$query_OBJ->bindValue(':tblNum_INT', $tblNum_INT);
$query_OBJ->bindValue(':tblUcoDataLine1UcoMax_INT', $tblUcoDataLine1UcoMax_INT);
$query_OBJ->execute();
echo $sqlCond_STR;//tbl_num = :tblNum_INT AND mat_state = 3 AND line_1_uco < :tblUcoDataLine1UcoMax_INT ORDER BY lined ASC, linsor ASC
```

Это рабочий код, запрос проходит успешно, нет никаких замен.

Кстати, вы ведь заметили что пропустили в своём SQL-запросе слово **WHERE**?

Совет : **никогда не используйте двойные(") кавычки**, используйте **одинарные**('), а кто знает, может из-за них у вас замена идёт? Максимум где их можно использовать, так это для вывода непечатных символов типа "\n".

Comment: Что за странные фантазии с двойными кавычками?